# Still can change the value of object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am trying to use mvvm light framework and build a very simple application. On application, you can create a person and add to the datagrid.

[image: App]
The mainviewmodel looks like

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        //private readonly IDataService _dataService;
        private readonly IPersonService _personService;

        private ObservableCollection<Person> _persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
        {
            get { return _persons; }
            set
            {
                _persons = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Persons");
            } 
        }

        Person _personInfo;

        public Person PersonInfo
        {
            get { return _personInfo; }
            set
            {
                _personInfo = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("PersonInfo");
            }
        }

        #region Command Object Declarations

        public RelayCommand QueryPersons { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand<Person> AddPerson { get; set; }


        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the WelcomeTitle property.
        /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
        /// </summary>
        public string WelcomeTitle
        {
            get
            {
                return "Simple MVVM";
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>

        public MainViewModel(IPersonService personService)
        {
            _personService = personService;
            PersonInfo = new Person();
            QueryPersons = new RelayCommand(_GetPersons);
            AddPerson = new RelayCommand<Person>(_AddPerson);
        }


        void _GetPersons()
        {
            Persons.Clear();
            foreach (var p in _personService.GetPersons())
            {
                Persons.Add(p);
                RaisePropertyChanged("PersonInfo");
            }
        }

        void _AddPerson(Person p)
        {
            _personService.AddPerson(p);
            _GetPersons();
            
        }
}
```

And the view, that you can add a new user looks like:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MvvmLight1.Views.AddPersonView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name:"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Surname:"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Gender:"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Street:"/>

        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding PersonInfo.Name,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding PersonInfo.Surname,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding PersonInfo.Gender,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding PersonInfo.Street,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="26" Command="{Binding AddPerson}" CommandParameter="{Binding PersonInfo}">Add person</Button>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My problem is, after add the user, I can still change the added values in datagrid. The picture will clarify, what I mean:
[image: App2]
And change the values in textbox:
[image]

As you can see, I can still change the values of added person, how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a new value to `PersonInfo` after you successfully added the new person using your service.

```
void _AddPerson(Person p){
  _personService.AddPerson(p);
  PersonInfo = new Person();
  _GetPersons();
}
```

After that the input fields are cleared and you can create a new user.

Answer (score 1):

After you added PersonInfo in Persons collection - you can reset that property to new instance.

```
void _AddPerson(Person p)
{
    _personService.AddPerson(p);
    PersonInfo = new Person();
    _GetPersons();

}
```